# Cannot connect to KeyServer for contract deployment from Visual Studio

Tags: solidity, blockapps, visual-studio

I am following the instructions from (https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio-8bdab2ff8a74#.k2y18h96h) to use the solidity extension (version 1.1.4.0) through Visual Studio.

I am not able to deploy the sample contract and I get the following error:

> key server not available
>
> Error Text Below
>   
>  Deployment to http://localhost:8000/ started!
>   
>  User used for deployment: testuser
>    
> User found: []
>    
> Please check if keyserver is running. If keyserver is running and deploy is failing due to insufficient gas, delete the user folder on key server and a new user will automatically be created

Also, while I was starting the initializing the bloc application using the command `bloc init`, I did not get the confirmation that the keyserver is listen. After running the `block init` the command simply moves to the next line without any error or confirmation.

Both the things could be related, but not sure. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I am good for now. :) I did some digging and found that the issue was not related to some missing steps. Port 8000 was already being used by the operating system PID4, so i moved to Port 8001 which resolved the issue.

If time permits, you can add a step a new interim step to check if port 8000 is already being used. Let me know and i can put something around that with screen prints.

Thanks for the prompt response